# fill a form from another page form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have 2 html page and there is same form in both of them, first page sends form data to database .i want to submit second page form through first page.

something like filling first page form by javascript and submit it.

page one:  
submit.php

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
   <input placeholder="user" type="text" name="user" id="user">
   <input placeholder="pass" type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
   <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

page two:  
send.php

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why is that your PHP files does not contain any php?

Comment: make a json of the data and decode it on the other page

Comment: i want to submit second page form throw first page. -- i dont understand what do you mean by that?

Comment: Why not just submit both forms data variables on the same page instead of going out to another page?

Comment: i have a website panel which is too messy, i want to make a simple panel that can submit by the main panel. @d3vdpro

Comment: "*.. form throw*" is suspicious to me?

Comment: i login to my website panel and want to send data easily, by a simple form. it's not a hacking project ! ;) @NanaPartykar

Comment: You could you AJAX to go out get the data and then post it to wherever you want.

Comment: @NanaPartykar maybe it's a typo for through?

Comment: If you want the user to fill in two different forms on two different pages, use a $_SESSION. If you want the user to fill in a form, and display these informations on a second page, you could use php or do it even with pure js (localStorage)

Comment: yes,that's it ! I corrected it :)) @LelioFaieta

Comment: user doesn't know about second page at all, and has no access to it. first page is a website for selling and its panel is too messy. my job is to make a simple form for adding new things to website by user. and i must make another website for sending data to panel. @Jonasw

Comment: @emad22552: messing with critical php (accessing databases) is not a good job for a beginner. Its still not clear what exactly is not working. If you cannot do it on your own, you should goto http://php.net and MDN and learn...

Comment: i'm not accessing other's database. a company asked me for making a simple form for its sellers that can sell more easily.that's all of it.thank you. @Jonasw

Comment: thank you all very much for helping, i'll pay attention to everything you said...

Comment: @emad2252: theres one important rule in informatics: _never trust the user_. Today there are bots out there that search for possible _mysql injections_ etc. A beginner (sorry, but i think you are one) shouldnt deal with this. If you do a mistake, your customers data can be leaked/stolen/modified/deleted , his page can be overtaken, and so on. Dont mess with this, at first learn a lot

Comment: I'm sorry.you are right...i really am a beginner!! :) your advice is fully correct...thanks. @Jonasw

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could install something called VUE.JS

https://vuejs.org/

You can use this and make two forms on one page, hide the second using some javascript and using VUEJS's 2 way binding / other stuff to submit the forms and handle the data on the PHP pages. This will do it without refreshing the page as well.

I'd recommend taking a quick read of vuejs, it could be a possible solution for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try send values over CURL when you submit first form.

```
function SendSecondForm($username, $password)
{
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"yoursite/send.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=$username&password=$password");
   $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
   curl_close ($ch);
}
```